# How can I delete unwanted keys in spacemacs org-cite/citar?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, ivy, spacemacs

I am trying to use org-cite and citar-embark to manage my citations. I am okay with selecting (multiple) keys and editing citation styles with `C-c C-x @` and `embark-act`. But the problem is, when I choose citation (keys) in the minibuffer, I couldn't delete keys I didn't want.

For example:

```
Keys (empty imput exits): Citation1;Citation2;
```

If I don't want `Citation2` and hit backspace, I quitted the whole minibuffer, rather than just deleting `Citation2`. I tried couple ways but nothing worked. I know `org-ref` can do what I wanted but I have to use `citar-embark` to keep the same citing style with my colleague. Can someone have any suggestion for this?

BTW, I use `ivy`. Command-log shown that when I hit backspace within the minibuffer, the action was `ivy-backward-delete-char` and then I quitted the minibuffer, if this info helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, this issue is unrelated to Spacemacs. It seems that ivy [does not support `completing-read-multiple` well?](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/3014)

I am using `vertico` and `consult` which work as the [described functionality](https://github.com/emacs-citar/citar/pull/163).

Possible suggestions:

1. Use vertico and consult.
2. (setq citar-select-multiple nil).
3. Use `citar-capf` completion instead of inserting citation with `org-cite-insert`.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks Tianshu! It seems the only way to fix that. But I am a heavy `ivy` user and have a lot of config based on that. Appreciate that but I think an ivy-specific solution suits better for my situation.

Comment: Then you can consider option 3 ;).